# dnf list available updates for locked packages

Tags: yum, dnf

With `yum versionlock status` I can get a list of available updates that are currently blocked by versionlock. With dnf this command doesn't seem to work.
I cannot find a dnf command that does the same. Is there perhaps another way?

Since dnf does not have a command like `dnf versionlock status`, I have created a small script to do sort of the same.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

LOCKED_LIST=( $(dnf -q versionlock) )

for LOCKED_ROW in "${LOCKED_LIST[@]}"; do
    dnf -q list available "${LOCKED_ROW%%-*}.x86_64" 2>/dev/null
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli_vs_yum.html?highlight=versionlock) and [here](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html?highlight=versionlock). It looks like you need to install `python3-dnf-plugin-versionlock` plugin in order to use it. But I could be misinterpreting this.

More info about the plugin can be found [here](https://dnf-plugins-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/versionlock.html).

Comment: I forgot to mention it is a CentOS 7 machine, and I installed the package yum install yum-plugin-versionlock.
The locking works well, but I still want to be notified about updates for locked packages.